React Native: Error updating property 'coordinate' of AIRMapMarker - NoSuchKeyException: latitude only on Android
I'm encountering a peculiar issue in my React Native application that's causing crashes specifically on Android devices, as reported by Firebase Crashlytics. The error message points to a NoSuchKeyException and a subsequent JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException, specifically citing a problem with updating the property 'coordinate' of a view managed by AIRMapMarker.
Here's the detailed error stack trace:
Caused by com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException: latitude
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue(ReadableNativeMap.java:113)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue(ReadableNativeMap.java:117)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getDouble(ReadableNativeMap.java:154)
       at com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapMarker.setCoordinate(AirMapMarker.java:159)
       at com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapMarkerManager.setCoordinate(AirMapMarkerManager.java:169)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:93)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackViewManagerSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:136)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:56)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.updateProperties(ViewManager.java:86)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createViewInstance(ViewManager.java:188)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView(ViewManager.java:115)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:281)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:194)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1110)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1081)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:175)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1648)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1659)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1129)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1045)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1622)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

This crash is occurring only on Android devices, and I haven't been able to reproduce it on iOS.
Here is my relevant code
{coordinates && 
  coordinates.map((coordinate, index) => (
   <Marker key={`coordinate_${index}`} coordinate={coordinate} />
      ))}


it is closed on gitHub - https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1073
